# why concatMap is not subscribing to all groupBy Observables rxjs?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I have a question why is this not writing to console the numbers 2,4,6? what is the explanation?

```
Observable.range(1, 6)
  .groupBy(n => n % 2 === 0)
  .concatMap(obs => obs)
  .subscribe((n) => console.log(n), null, () => console.log('complete concatMap'))

// this is the output
1 -
3 -
5 -
complete concatMap
```

Answer (score 3):

The basic problem is that you're using `concatMap` that subscribes to the next Observable only when the previous one completed. `groupBy` emits two `GroupedObservable`s so it subscribes to the first one and I think before it can subscribe to the second one the chain completes. This means the observer receives the `complete` notification from the first `GroupedObservable` and therefore you never see values from the second `GroupedObservable` (to be honest I'm not 100% sure it really happens like this but that makes sense to be without further investigating you example).

So if you want only the second group you could do:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

Observable.range(1, 6)
  .groupBy(n => n % 2 === 0)
  .filter(o => o.key === true)
  .concatMap(obs => obs)
  .subscribe((n) => console.log(n), null, () => console.log('complete concatMap'))
```

See live demo (open console): https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs5-sfused

I checked the source code and `groupBy` completes all groups after receiving the `complete` notification (which it does after receiving all values from `range`) and therefore there's never space for `concatMap` to subscribe to the second Observable.

See this: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/groupBy.ts#L200-L210

Comment: thanks for you answer, I would have expected that concatMap put the second observable (even numbers ) in a queue and subscribe after the first Observable(odd numbers) was completed, but I guess I'm wrong.

how would you do to get something like this 

`1-3-5 -2-4-6`



because with mergeMap i got this  `1-2-3-4-5-6`


and with switchMap this 1-2-4-6

Comment: I agree it's a little unexpected but if you look at the source code that's what it really does. I was thinking how to do it but I couldn't figure any smart solution without splitting the chain into two and using an intermediate Subject which feel kind of lame to me. If you don't need to use `groupBy` you could do the same with `scan` I think.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that `groupBy` operator emits `Subjects` for each key.

Concat map subscribes to subsequent `Subject` only after the first one is completed, i.e. it misses a chance to catch items from subsequent `Subject` because all of the sub-streams emit values in the same time.

Kudos to: https://blog.angularindepth.com/those-hidden-gotchas-within-rxjs-7d5c57406041

**TL;DR:**

[GroupBy](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/groupBy) receives `subjectSelector` as a 4th argument. You can use it to force using `ReplaySubject` instead of `Subject` *(default)*.

```
Observable.range(1, 6)
  .groupBy(
    n => n % 2 === 0,
    null, 
    null,
    () => new ReplaySubject() // <-- Here we go
  )
  .concatMap(obs => obs)
  .subscribe((n) => console.log(n))
```

[Demo on RxViz](https://rxviz.com/v/j8nXeMyO)